# Ant Design Form field with array of objects

Tags: typescript, forms, antd

I want to edit an entity with one-to-many relation

```
{
  id: 1,
  title: 'Title',
  tags: [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
  ],
}
```

With the code

```
<Form.Item
      name={["tags", "id"]}
    >

      <Select mode={'multiple'} {...selectProps} />
    </Form.Item>
```

On submit I get such object:

```
{
  id: 1,
  title: 'Title',
  tags: { id: [1, 2]},
}
```

How can I get tags as array of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `normalize` callback on `Form.Item`

Comment: Hi I am new to ant design I gave normalize prop but callback is not being called ?